# Google Apps Script: passing error into templated HTML

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have the following code:

code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Test', 'showTestForm')
      .addToUi();
}

function showTestForm() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('TestForm');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'TEST');
}

function Test(formObject){
  Logger.log("TEST")
  var a = new Error( "Allready present "+ formObject);
  a.error_code = 99;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
  throw a;
}
```

TestForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        function onFailure(error) {   
            var keys = Object.keys(error);
            alert(JSON.stringify(keys));
            alert(JSON.stringify(error.message));
            alert(JSON.stringify(error.error_code));
        }

        function onSuccess() {
            alert("Success");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).Test('1')" />
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I open TestForm from menu and press "Save" I've got following log from Logger:

```
[18-12-24 23:08:24:765 PST] TEST
[18-12-24 23:08:24:766 PST] {"message":"Allready present 1","error_code":99}
```

So I see, that error object have properties 'message' and 'error_code'. But in browser I've got following alerts:

```
["name"]
"Error: Allready present 1"
undefined
```

So I see, that recived error object has only one empty (i've checked) property "name". But if I but refer to the property "message, I've got string like in original object (but not the same). And it looks like that object haven't poperty "error_code".
What's the matter?

Comment: What does error.name show? Also try `alert(JSON.stringify(error['error_code']));`

Comment: @TheMaster: `""` and `undefined` respectively

Comment: Try to pass the regular object literal as in a = {message: message, statusCode: statusCode} instead of calling the Error constructor

Comment: Error object is a standard built in object. You can't just add properties to it. Only name and message are valid properties. But you can include a object in your message. ``var a = new Error( JSON.stringify({msg:"Allready present "+ formObject,code:99}));``

Comment: nothing changed. `error.msg` and `error.code` still undefined and `error.message` is `Error: {"msg":Allready present 1","code":99}`

Comment: Parse it. `JSON.parse(error.message).msg` or  `JSON.parse(error.message).Error.msg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance with the proposal of [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) it is necessary to do this:

code.gs

```
function Test(formObject){
    var a = new Error( JSON.stringify({msg:"Allready present "+ formObject,code:99}));
    throw a;
}
```

TestForm.html

```
// removing "Error: " from message string to get our json back
var json = error.message.replace("Error: ",'')
var msg = JSON.parse(json).msg;
var code = JSON.parse(json).code;
```

That is, we put json into the attribute `message` of the `Error` object, and then, by cutting our json, we parse it and get the necessary values.

This is not exactly the answer to the question, but a good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**I thought you might like a complete working example as I know this stuff can be quite frustrating.**

This a simple example templated HTML file that can be used as a dialog or a webapp.  All it does is create a Google Doc file with todays date in the header and footer of each page and it puts the file into the same directory as the spreadsheet which contains the script.  That's it.  I use the Chrome Browser.  I don't even care if my scripts won't run on another browser.

Here's the HTML: (FileName:'docwithdate.html')

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('resources') ?>
    <?!= include('css') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?!= include('form') ?>
    <?!= include('script') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Resources: (FileName: 'resources.html')

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The CSS: (FileName: 'css.html')

```
<style>
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
input[type="button"]{padding:0 0 2px 0;}
</style>
```

The Form: (FileName: form.html) This is probably push the templating idea a little far.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();processForm(this);" >
  <input type="text" id="txt1" name="filename" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The Javascript: [FileName: 'script.html')

```
<script>
    function createFile(){
      var name=document.getElementById('filename').value;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        var html='<br /><a href="'+ rObj.url +'" onClick="google.script.host.close();">Go To File:' + rObj.filename + '</a>';
        $(html).appendTo("body");
      })
      .createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name);
    }

    function getInputObject(obj) {//I'm probably doing something wrong here. But this is what I had to do to get the object with the properties that I desired.  So if you have another way.  Go for it.
      var rObj={};
      for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++){
        if(obj[i].type=="text"){
          rObj[obj[i].name]=obj[i].value;
        }
        console.log('Object.keys(rObj): %s',Object.keys(rObj).join(', '));
      }
      return rObj;
    }

    function processForm(obj){
      var fObj=getInputObject(obj);
      var name=fObj.filename;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
        var html='<br /><a href="'+ rObj.url +'" onClick="google.script.host.close();">Go To File:' + rObj.filename + '</a>';
        $(html).appendTo("body");
      })
      .createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name);
    }
    console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

The Google Script: (FileName: Code.gs)

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem("Open Templated Google Doc", 'showMyDialog')
  .addToUi()
}

function createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name){
  Logger.log(name);
  var doc=DocumentApp.create(name);//Creates a google doc
  var fldrs=DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).getParents();
  while(fldrs.hasNext()){
    var fldr=fldrs.next();
    if(fldr.getName()=="Create Templated Google Doc App"){
      var folder=fldr;
    }
  }
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, doc.getId());//puts doc file into same directory as the spreadsheet that contains the script
  doc.addHeader().appendParagraph(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"));
  doc.addFooter().appendParagraph(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"));
  //doc.getBody().getChild(0).removeFromParent();
  doc.saveAndClose()
  var rObj={url:doc.getUrl(),filename:doc.getName()}
  return rObj;
}

function showMyDialog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('docwithdate').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'My Doc with Date');
}

function doGet(){//if you want a web app this is helpful
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('docwithdate').evaluate();
}

function include(filename){//this is the include that the template uses
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

It's a pretty simple script.  I hope it helps you get a start.

Comment: my question was about passing an error object, and in your example there is nothing about it

Comment: Passing an error object is just like passing any other object

Comment: cool. but it doesn't work as suspected, as you can see in my example

Comment: But your function test doesn’t return anything

Comment: yes, but it throws an exception `throw a;`. I have allready a HTMLOutput displayed to user, he submitted a form and now I should return an error

Comment: I don’t see any form. The only thing that function test receives is a string

Comment: I apologize, here is the code after the simplification and there is no form here. In this case, the user clicks the Save button and the code on the "server" throws an error, which should return to the handler `onFailure`. And my question is about properties of recived `error` object.