# Output data from googlesheet via htmlservice using Google Apps Script

Tags: html, json, google-apps-script

My task is  to serve data from spreadsheet. There is pultiple positions with prizes. I want to serve it to user using html template and HtmlService

I have prepared html template with places where I want serve data. 
I coded script that colects data from googleSheet and store in objects.

js in google apps env:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
       .createHtmlOutputFromFile('kosztorys.html')
       .setWidth(500)
       .setHeight(550)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'Some title');
```

Im confused right now and dont know what to do with that. Ive been tried some solutions found in internet but it doesnt work. How to put data into template?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need something like this:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
       .createHtmlOutputFromFile('kosztorys')
       .evaluate()
       .setWidth(500)
       .setHeight(550)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'Some title');
```

Generally, you needn't supply the `.html` for the filename because Google Script adds it for you.  So in your case the program was looking for a file named `kosxtorys.html.html`.

[Here's an example of a templated HTML webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926151/7215091)

Here's an example showing how to get the contents of a spreadsheet into a dialog.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Read Data from Active Sheet', 'readDataFromSheet')
  .addToUi();
}


function readDataFromSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html="<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    html+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(i==0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</td>',vA[i][j]);
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',vA[i][j]);
        Logger.log('vA[%s][%s]=%s>',i,j,vA[i][j]);
      }
    }
    html+='</tr>';
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Reading Data From A Spreadsheet')
}
```

The is what the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

And this is what the dialog looks like:

[image]

There's many ways to output your data from a spreadsheet it depends a lot upon your data.  But this is one of many.

Comment: not really. Templated HTML doesnt resolve my question: How to put data into html from Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Adam Serocki You said you were using HTML template but I noticed that you didn’t have an evaluate in htmlservice method.