# Cascading dropdowns in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am posting this message because I am stuck in the design of a web app.

The purpose of this one is to save the data entered in a form (not Google Forms) in a sheet.
The problem I have is the dropdowns. I would like to have 4 of them (site, sector, zone and room) and that they are in cascade. Indeed, selecting a site allows to display only in the sector dropdown those related to it. And so on until the rooms.

I managed to link the sites with the sectors but I am blocked for the sector to zone and zone to room part.

1. Here is my gs code :

// Déclaration des constantes

const URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QG_eMv2xdYB7tCh80Lm7oVbRD_PIioRG8qNjcxlaSuo/edit#gid=1898395234';

//Methode GET

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp');
  var sites = getSites();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.sites = sites;

  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

// Methode POST

```
 function doPost(e) {
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
   var name = e.parameters.name.toString();
   var site = e.parameters.site.toString();
   var secteur = e.parameters.secteur.toString();
   AddRecord(name, site, secteur);  
   var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp');
   var sites = getSites();
   htmlOutput.message = 'Votre demande a été enregistrée.';
   htmlOutput.sites = sites;

   return htmlOutput.evaluate();  
 }
```

// Récupérer les Sites

```
function getSites() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites/Secteurs"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++){
    if(return_array.indexOf(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
      return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
    }
  }
  return return_array;  
}
```

// Récupérer les Secteurs en fonction d'un site rentré en paramètre

```
function getSecteurs(site) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lovSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites/Secteurs"); 
  var getLastRow = lovSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++){
      if(lovSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === site) {
        return_array.push(lovSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array;  
}
```

// Enregistrer les données dans le sheet

```
function AddRecord(name, site, secteur) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Demandes");
  dataSheet.appendRow([IncrementId(), new Date(), getUser(), site, secteur, name]);
}
```

// Récupérer l'URL

```
function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

// Incrémentation automatique de l'id

```
function IncrementId(){
  var id = 1;
  var year = extractYear().toString().substr(-2);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Demandes");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue(); 
  var lastCellSplit = lastCell.split("_");
  var idSplit = parseInt(lastCellSplit[0]); 
  var yearSplit = lastCellSplit[1]; 
  if (lastCell =="ID"){
    var id = 1 + "_" + year; 
  } else if(year == yearSplit){
    var id = (idSplit + 1)+"_"+yearSplit;
  } else {
    var id = 1 + "_" + year; 
  }
  return id;
}
```

// Récupérer l'année

```
function extractYear(){
  var date = new Date ();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return year;
}
```

// Récupérer l'adresse mail de l'utilisateur

```
function getUser() {
  var theUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return theUser;
}
```

2. And here is the .html code :

   2.1 Script part :

   ```
   function GetSecteur(site) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      secteur.length = 0;
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = "";
      option.id = "";
      option.text = "";
      secteur.appendChild(option);
      ar.forEach(function(item, index) {    
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = item;
        option.text = item;
        option.id = item;
        secteur.appendChild(option);    
      });
    }).getSecteurs(site);
   ```

   };

   2.2. Form part :
   [sorry but i cant add code for this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ014.png)
   [image]

Would you have any idea how to get the four dropdowns to link with each other? I tried to duplicate what I did for the first step but it doesn't work ...

If you have questions, don't hesitate to ask me. Thanks in advance for your feedback and sorry for my english.

Comment: Section "2.2 Body part:" is missing. Is it what you want to be written?

Comment: yeah, i just add this now. But this is a picture, i cant add the code :(

Comment: Your template doesn't seem to be including the JavaScript or at least I don't see it.

Comment: Here's an example of a html template that includes CSS and JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926151/7215091