# How to serve an HTML page with js function in another file whle passing an object as variable using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to pass an `Object` while serving the page, but this is resulting in a blank page, throwing NO error:

```
const getNewPageContent = (clientType, clientName, clientId, userId, userFirstName, userLastName) => {
  if (clientType === "AP") {
    const apDashboardJs = "ap_dashboard_js";
    let apDahboardHtml = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ap_dashboard_js");
    apDahboardHtml.obj = obj = {
      typeOfClient: clientType,
      nameOfClient: clientName,
      idOfClient: clientId,
      userFirstName: userFirstName,
      userLastName: userLastName
    }
    const apDashboardHtml2Content = apDahboardHtml.evaluate().getContent();
    const apDashboardHtmlWindow = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ap_dashboard");
    apDashboardHtmlWindow[apDashboardJs] = apDashboardHtml2Content;
    return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
}
```

Here is the `HTML` file to be "served":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <h3 id="navbar-title">Dashboard</h3>
    <div class="user-info">
      <div class="user-avatar">
        <a href="#"><i class="bx bx-user avatar avatar-sm"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="user-details">
        <div class="user-dropdown">
          <select id="user-dropdown" class="styled-select">
              <option value="" id="full-name-option" selected></option>
              <option value="Logout">Logout</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ap_dashboard_css').getContent(); ?>
<?!= ap_dashboard_js ?>
</html>
```

Here is the `js` file:

```
<script>
function addEventListenerToDashBtn() {
  const dashboardContainer = document.getElementById('dashboard-container');
  if (dashboardContainer) {
    dashboardContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dashboardContainer.classList.toggle("activeBtn");
    });
  }
}
addEventListenerToDashBtn();

let cardsContainer = document.querySelector('.cards-container');
let navbarTitle = document.querySelector('#navbar-title');
let sideBar = document.querySelector('.side-bar');
let arrowCollapse = document.querySelector('#logo-name__icon');
let topLevelList = document.getElementById('top-level-list');

arrowCollapse.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  sideBar.classList.toggle('collapse');
  arrowCollapse.classList.toggle('collapse');
  cardsContainer.classList.toggle('stretch')
  navbarTitle.classList.toggle('stretch')

  if (arrowCollapse.classList.contains('collapse')) {
    arrowCollapse.className = 'bx bx-arrow-from-left logo-name__icon collapse';
    topLevelList.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    arrowCollapse.className = 'bx bx-arrow-from-right logo-name__icon';
  }
});

sideBar.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target === arrowCollapse) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});

  let clientName = <?!= obj.nameOfClient ?>;
  let clientType = <?!= obj.typeOfClient ?>;
  let clientId = <?!= obj.idOfClient ?>;
  let userId = <?!= obj.userId ?>;
  let userFirstName = <?!= obj.userFirstName ?>;
  let userLastName = <?!= obj.userLastName ?>;
  let fullName = userFirstName + " " + userLastName;
  document.getElementById('clientNameHeader').textContent = clientName;

  const fullNameOption = document.getElementById('full-name-option');
  fullNameOption.value = fullName;
  fullNameOption.text = fullName
</script>
```

and this is the function calling the one that serves the html page:

```
const signIn = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(event); // Prevent the default form submission behavior.
  const userId = document.getElementById("email-input").value;
  const pwd = document.getElementById("pwd-input").value;
  //Check if the login is valid
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(validSession) {
      const clientType = validSession.clientType;
      const clientName = validSession.clientName;
      const clientId = validSession.id;
      const userId = validSession.userId;
      const userFirstName = validSession.userFirstName;
      const userLastName = validSession.userLastName;
      if (clientType === "AP") {
        console.log("AP Page called successfully.");
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(newPageContent) {
            document.body.innerHTML = newPageContent;
            [...document.getElementsByTagName("script")].forEach(o => new Function(`return function(){${o.innerText}}()`)());
          })
          .getNewPageContent(clientType, clientName, clientId, userId, userFirstName, userLastName);

      } else if (validSession === "wrong password") {
        document.body.innerHTML = validSession
      }
    })
    .checkLogin("log-in credentials", "", userId, pwd); // Pass the parsed storedSession as an object
}
```

This is where `signIn()` gets called:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="wp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.3.0/crypto-js.js"></script>
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Login_css').getContent(); ?>
  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Login_js').getContent(); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-page">

    <div class="login-dashboard">
      <div id="login-header">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <span>Please enter your login details below</span>
      </div>
      <form class="form-login" onsubmit="signIn(event)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email-input" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="pwd-input" required>
        </div>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the details of the relationship between `signIn` and your showing scripts? It seems that in your showing scripts, `signIn` is not used. For example, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Have you tried - [Templated Html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926151/7215091

Comment: Just updated the question with the location where `signIn()` gets called, @Tanaike!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying and updating your question. Your showing script is the whole script for correctly replicating your current issue. Is my understanding correct? By the way, I thought that your variables of `let clientName = <?!= obj.nameOfClient ?>;`, `let clientType = <?!= obj.typeOfClient ?>;`, and so on are required to be modified to `let clientName = "<?!= obj.nameOfClient ?>";`, `let clientType = "<?!= obj.typeOfClient ?>";`, and so on, respectively. I thought that each value is required to be enclosed by `"` or `'`. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: I actually changed those and the page `ap_dashboard.html` gets called, but it only shows a blank page, with no error in the console whatsoever, @Tanaike!

Comment: @Cooper, because there will be multiple pages, I am trying to keet the functions and files separated as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. But, I think that the suggested modifications in my comment are required to be done. And, I noticed one more modification point. I think that `return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);` should be `return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();`. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: Exactly! At the of day, my poor coding skills get me completely blind. Thank you, @Tanaike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `but this is resulting in a blank page, throwing NO error:`, the reason for this might be `return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);` of the function `getNewPageContent` at the Google Apps Script side. So, please modify this as follows.

#### Form:

```
return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

#### To:

```
return apDashboardHtmlWindow.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).getContent();
```

And also, in your script, I think that there is another modification point. In your script, you are using the replaced variables at "Here is the js file:" as follows.

```js
let clientName = <?!= obj.nameOfClient ?>;
let clientType = <?!= obj.typeOfClient ?>;
let clientId = <?!= obj.idOfClient ?>;
let userId = <?!= obj.userId ?>;
let userFirstName = <?!= obj.userFirstName ?>;
let userLastName = <?!= obj.userLastName ?>;
```

I think that this should be modified to be as follows. Please enclose the variable by `"` or `'` as follows.

```js
let clientName = "<?!= obj.nameOfClient ?>";
let clientType = "<?!= obj.typeOfClient ?>";
let clientId = "<?!= obj.idOfClient ?>";
let userId = "<?!= obj.userId ?>";
let userFirstName = "<?!= obj.userFirstName ?>";
let userLastName = "<?!= obj.userLastName ?>";
```

#### Note:

I don't know your actual script. So, if `.side-bar` of `let sideBar = document.querySelector('.side-bar');` and `#logo-name__icon` of `let arrowCollapse = document.querySelector('#logo-name__icon')` and `clientNameHeader` of `document.getElementById('clientNameHeader').textContent = clientName` have already been existing in your HTML, please don't worry.

If those don't exist, those might be another possible issue at `sideBar.addEventListener('click', (event) => {,,,})`, `arrowCollapse.addEventListener('click', (event) => {,,,})` and `document.getElementById('clientNameHeader').textContent = clientName;`. Please be careful about this.